# Alter trigger Oracle

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql, ddl

Does alter trigger hang if a table is locked by some DML operation
? 
What kind of exception does it throw? Resource busy 0054 or some other exception...?  I have tried to reproduce this scenario but in vain.

Comment: Post the scenario's you did try. On a conceptual level, the question is weird since you should have triggers before you have entered any data in a table. Consider the fact the data already in the table, may not be in line with the content of the new trigger. But, better late than never, to have a good trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test case.

Open 2 sqlplus sessions, run the following in the first to set the test up:

```
create table stall_table
(
  a number
);

create or replace trigger stall_session
before insert on stall_table
begin
  DBMS_LOCK.sleep(10000);
end;
```

Then, execute in session 1:

```
SQL> insert into stall_table values ( 1 ) ;
```

Execute in session 2:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger stall_session
before insert on stall_table
begin
  DBMS_LOCK.sleep(10000);
end;
/
```

You'll get, after some time:

```
create or replace trigger stall_session
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object


SQL>
```

... which answers your question.

Comment: Thanks Phil! I was able to reproduce the alter trigger lock condition on dml insert statement.. I'll have to time the Alter trigger part so as to automatically throw exception after some time.. Perhaps, ddl_lock_timeout should work..

Comment: Ddl_lock_timeout does not work.. It works only when a full table lock is required and wants until the table lock is released..